# How to use NetCat for Windows to send a binary file to a TCP connection?

Tags: linux, windows, docker, netcat

If I want to transfer a binary file "binary.bin" (located in the same directory as NetCat) to IP address 127.0.0.1 port 1200 using TCP, how do I specify this using [NetCat](http://www.rodneybeede.com/Compile_Netcat_on_Windows_using_MinGW.html) for windows?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution. Its

```
nc 127.0.0.1 1200 < binary.bin
```

In addition, if the response needs to be saved then

```
nc 127.0.0.1 1200 < binary.bin > response.bin
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send it from a linux distribution to anybody, including windows PCs you can do something like this:

```
{ echo -ne "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\r\n"; cat path/to/your/file/binary.bin ; } | nc -l 1200
```

The receiving end then just needs to browse to your IP Address in his web browser and gets a prompt to download.
Needless to say port 1200 needs to be forwarded if you're behind a router.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to share with you the complete solution that you can use to expose/make available a file via a network between remote computers with Netcat.

I use this perfect and simple solution to share a file between Docker Containers in a portable way without defining `Docker Volume` or installing `ssh` in the Docker container.

**A simple bash function that exposes the file on the source machine:**

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# make the file available for another machine via the network
#
# this runs in the background to avoid blocking the main script execution
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function exposeFile() {
    local file port
    file="$1"
    port=1384

    echo "exposing the file for another machine with..."
    echo "   file: $file"
    echo "   port: $port"

    while :
    do
        { echo -ne "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\r\n"; cat "$file" ; } | nc  -l "$port"
    done
}
```

The endless loop is necessary if you want to download the file more than one time because after the download `Netcat` exists.

**Call the bash method from your main script to expose the file when you need it:**

```
#!/bin/bash
...
exposeFile "path/to/the/file.zip" &
```

**Then you can use the a simple `wget` to download the file on the source machine:**

```
function fileDownload {
    echo "downloading the file..."

    local fileHome file
    fileHome="/download/directory/"
    file="myfile.zip"

    local remoteHost remotePort
    remoteHost="remote-host-or-ip"
    remotePort=1384

    mkdir -p "$fileHome"
    wget -O "$fileHome/$file" "$remoteHost":"$remotePort"
}
```

I hope that this will help you to save some time ;)