# Combining interchangable docker applications

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to use multiple individual docker files/containers in one combined application. Suppose I have three docker containers. Two containers, `Framework A` and `Framework B`, that process data in a two different ways, but give the same output. The other container, `main`, will process that output. Now in my application I would like to use either `Framework A` or `Framework B`, or perhaps both.

I looked at a solution to [combine multiple docker containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27214757/docker-combine-multiple-images), but this does not seem to be supported by docker and is also not exactly what I want. So I looked into [Docker volumes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27421322/in-docker-how-can-i-share-files-between-containers-and-then-save-them-to-an-ima), but I don't really want to 'write' or store the data from the two individual frameworks, just pass it to the third container. I also read about `docker-compose`, but again this does not seem to be exactly what I want.

Suppose that in the `main` container I have some python code, that will call some other code from either `Framework A` or `Framework B`, and data then gets passed from either of those two to `main` (a python object, array or something similar). What would be the best way to achieve this? And is this easily interchangeable, given that the outputs of `framework A` and `framework B` are the same?

Comment: How is the data passed? Compose sounds like what you want, but the requirement seems kinda woolly atm.

Comment: I've updated the question a bit to (hopefully) more clearly state what I would like to achieve

Comment: What are `framework A` and `framework B` and how do you hope to pass data into them? Are they services that are always running and you can send them data? Are they shell scripts you can pass data to? Something else?

Comment: They are basically scripts that will take data, so they are not always running, I  want to fire them up just when they're needed.

Comment: How much data is being passed from main to framework and back?  Not sure why you discounted data volumes, that would be the simplest solution.

Comment: I was hoping there would be some more 'intuitive' way, where I could just run a function inside another like I would normally run a function, also to get easier linking.  But I think I'll resort to Docker volumes now then.