# Run bash command before running container

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

I want to run a pre-existing Docker image like so:

```
docker run -d --name cdt-selenium selenium/standalone-firefox:3.4.0-chromium
```

So there is no Dockerfile that I control for this image. However, I would like to copy some files into this container.

If I did control the Dockerfile, I would like to run these commands:

```
RUN mkdir -p /root/cdt-tests/csv-data
COPY ./csv-data/* /root/cdt-tests/csv-data
```

Is there a way to run those commands in the same line as the Docker run command above?

I tried this:

```
docker run -d --name cdt-selenium selenium/standalone-firefox:3.4.0-chromium
docker exec cdt-selenium mkdir -p /root/cdt-tests/csv-data
docker cp cdt-selenium:/root/cdt-tests/csv-data ./csv-data
```

but I get a permissions error on the docker exec line

Comment: ah, perhaps I can use docker exec, after calling docker run

Comment: Why aren't you importing these files as a volume?

Comment: @BMitch yes, I agree, that was my other question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44146561/selenium-cannot-find-file-running-in-separate-container....the current question here is a workaround, because I could not figure out how to get volumes to work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All images have a `FROM` line, and that can be any other image. So you can make a Dockerfile with:

```
FROM selenium/standalone-firefox:3.4.0-chromium
USER root
RUN mkdir -p /root/cdt-tests/csv-data
COPY ./csv-data/* /root/cdt-tests/csv-data
USER seluser
```

that will build your own image with your commands run.

You'd build it and create your own tag:

```
docker build -t alexander/selenium:3.4.0-chromium .
```

And then run it:

```
docker run -d --name cdt-selenium alexander/selenium:3.4.0-chromium
```

---

Edit: the exec command you ran failed because docker runs this container as a different user. You can see that in their [Dockerfile](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/blob/master/StandaloneFirefox/Dockerfile#L16). To solve that, run the exec with the root user option (`-u root`):

```
docker exec -u root cdt-selenium mkdir -p /root/cdt-tests/csv-data
```

Comment: thanks, I will try this - first though I'd like to try the docker exec/docker cp method - I updated the question - any idea how to get around that permissions problem I mention?

Comment: I've updated the answer to cover the seluser that Selenium uses inside their container.

Comment: thanks, also using sudo seemed to work (which is surprising) => docker exec cdt-selenium sudo mkdir -p /root/cdt-tests/csv-data

Comment: is selenium server really ok with absolute paths to files on the fs?

Comment: yeah both these techniques seem to work without errors, but selenium still cannot find the files at /root/cdt-tests/csv-data/X...not really sure what's happening, any ideas?

Comment: one clue is, when I run this:  docker exec -u root cdt-selenium echo $(ls -a /root/cdt-tests), it says that there is no such directory as /root/cdt-tests, so maybe that directory is not being created correctly, idk, very strange

Comment: aka, "ls: /root/cdt-tests: No such file or directory", weird.

Comment: Since Selenium is running as seluser inside the container, I doubt it can see files under /root. It may also depend on the file permissions of the source (host).

Comment: This is on my local machine and the exec/cp commands complete successfully, so should not be permissions problem, but at the same time, the files don't appear to exist in the container, because the ls command fails. weird.

Comment: Selinium doesn't run on your local machine, it runs in a container, as a different user.

Comment: Right, I am aware of that, and sometimes selenium might run an another machine altogether. That's what makes me think, that maybe the problem that I think I have, is not the problem I really have.