# sharing files between two Docker containers

Tags: docker, devops

How can I share files between 2 different container? I need some Yamal files settings for exist container.
someone have simple example?

Comment: Read volumes documentation. If you want a specific answer, add details to your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use NetCat for Windows to send a binary file to a TCP connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040817/how-to-use-netcat-for-windows-to-send-a-binary-file-to-a-tcp-connection)

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple toy example that demonstrate a *basic* use of volumes in docker

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"
services:
    container1:
        image: alpine:latest
        volumes:
            - type: bind
              source: ./mydata
              target: /opt/app/static
        entrypoint:
            - cat
            - /opt/app/static/conf.yml

    container2:
        image: alpine:latest
        volumes:
            - type: bind
              source: ./mydata
              target: /opt/app/static2
        entrypoint:
            - cat
            - /opt/app/static2/conf.yml
```

conf.yml (reside under `mydata` folder)

```
a simple text file
```

the containers get mounted with the local `mydata` folder

when running `docker-compose up` the containers get created and output the content of the `conf.yml` file to stdout

```
...
container2_1  | a simple text file
container1_1  | a simple text file
```

the docker-compose file is annotated with version `3.7` but compatible to version `2.4+` thus it can be also written like

```
volumes:
  - ./mydata:/opt/app/static
```

Answer (score 0):

You should mount the same folder/volume to all running containers:
Example:
docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: "3"

services: 
  first: 
    image: ubuntu:18.04
    command: /bin/sh -c "while sleep 1000; do :; done"
    volumes: 
      - "test:/data"

  second:
    image: ubuntu:18.04
    command: /bin/sh -c "while sleep 1000; do :; done"
    volumes:
      - "test:/data"

volumes:
  test:
```

Run:

```sh
docker-compose up -d
docker-compose exec first /bin/sh -c "echo 'Hello shared folder' > /data/example.txt"
docker-compose exec second /bin/sh -c "cat /data/example.txt"
```

You will see: `Hello shared folder`
We share same volume between two containers first write file and second read.