# Share single files between docker containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to share single files between docker containers

```
ContainerA:
- file-1
- file-2
- file-3
- shared-file

ContainerB
- file-a
- file-b
- file-c
- shared-file
```

It is not possible to share a complete volume for me.
The path in the container is not the same.

Comment: Do you mean a directory with "complete volume" or do you also mean a file? Because it's possible to mount a single file as a "volume".

Comment: Imagine that a seed file is created when the container is started. The same seed file should be used in another container. The application accessing the seed has hardcoded paths and in the target directory are other files that must not be shared.

Comment: Can you `COPY` the file from one image to another, instead of trying to use volumes?

Comment: @DavidMaze if i do this, a change  is only in one container.
maybe i will copy it... but at the moment i can not ensure there is no IO on the file.

Comment: The requirements have changed.
I no longer need the same file in both containers. a similar file is sufficient.
there will probably be no write access in operation after all.

so my problem can be solved with https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/ 
COPY --from=0 {src} {target}

I leave the question open for a while in case the problem can be solved in general.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use NetCat for Windows to send a binary file to a TCP connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040817/how-to-use-netcat-for-windows-to-send-a-binary-file-to-a-tcp-connection)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `docker` defaults to directories as volumes and only bind-mounts a file when the source is an existing file it is a bit harder to use.

With the `file` you want to share in your current directory you can use bind-mounts in `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
services:
  app1:
    # ...
    volumes:
      - ./file:/path/to/file1:rw
  app2:
    # ...
    volumes:
      - ./file:/path/to/file2:rw
```

This is requires the file to already exist outside the containers. See also the caveats with bind-mounting files in [jubnzv's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66473273/share-single-files-between-docker-containers/66473649#66473649).

Depending on your use case maybe a better workaround could be using [symlinks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) and mounting the shared file in a directory volume:

```
# tree layout in containers:
ContainerA:
|- shared/
|   ` shared-file
`- app_folder_a/
    |- file-1
    |- file-2
    |- file-3
    `- shared-file-a -> /shared/shared-file


ContainerB:
|- shared/
|   ` shared-file
`- app_folder_b/
    |- file-a
    |- file-b
    |- file-c
    `- shared-file-b -> /shared/shared-file
```

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml
services:
  app1:
    # ...
    volumes:
      - ./shared/:/shared/:rw
  app2:
    # ...
    volumes:
      - ./shared/:/shared/:rw
```

Or if you do not want/can have the file or the shared directory on the host you can use named volumes with symlinks:

```yaml
services:
  app1:
    # ...
    volumes:
      - shared:/app_folder_a
  app2:
    # ...
    depends_on:
      - app1
    volumes:
      - shared:/shared

volumes:
  shared:
```

and the shared file symlinked in containerB:

```
ContainerB:
|- shared/
|   ` ...
`- app_folder_b/
    |- file-a
    |- file-b
    |- file-c
    `- shared-file-b -> /shared/shared-file-a
```

The important part here is that when creating the new volume `shared` the first time `docker` will prepopulate it with the contents of the target directory in the container. So to work correctly `app1` need to be started first so the `shared` volume is populated with the contents of `app_folder_a` - therefore the `depends_on`.

With this you then have the `shared` volume, populated with the contents of containerA's `/app_folder_a/` and mounted to the same as well as on containerB's `/shared/` while `/app_folder_b/shared-file-b` is a symlink to `/shared/shared-file-a`.

Comment: This is almost the solution to my problem.
Now I just have to get it implemented. 
It is difficult to create a link to a file that does not exist yet. If I manage it I will publish it

Answer (score 0):

You can use volumes to share individual files, rather than directories.  But in some cases, you can't write correctly to the mounted files.

Here is a minimal example:

```sh
echo 'Test.' > /tmp/1.txt
docker run -it --user $(id -u):$(id -g) --rm -v /tmp/1.txt:/tmp/2.txt:rw alpine
```

Inside the container you can access `/tmp/1.txt` from the host system using in the `/tmp/2.txt` path:

```sh
/ $ cat /tmp/2.txt
Test.
/ $ echo '123' > /tmp/2.txt 
/ $ cat /tmp/2.txt
123
```

But some utilities will try to create a new inode when writing to the file. For example:

```sh
/ $ cp etc/sysctl.conf  /tmp/2.txt 
cp: can't create '/tmp/2.txt': File exists
```

The point is that mounting a file as a volume mounts a specific inode inside the container. Some tools that modify files replace the inode with a new one. But you can't do this because you mount a specific inode that points to your file.

Thus, you will need to mount a directory containing the inodes that you can modify inside the container. For more information, see the [docker volumes documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).

Comment: I also can not reproduce the error, writing works just fine and this is the expected behavior - at least when writing into the same inode because you are correct: trying to write by replacing the inode - i.e. overwriting the file with a new one - _will_ fail. This makes bind-mounting a file unsuitable for some use cases.

Answer (score 0):

If containerA creates a file at a certain path and overwrites symlinks I don't think it's possible to do this with a "clean" approach (otherwise check acran's answer).

The only way I can come up with is:

- start ContainerA
- wait for the file to be created
- get the file (e.g. docker cp)
- start ContainerB with the seed

However there a few problems e.g. if ContainerA crashed ContainerB needs to be recreated as well or you need to copy the file again.

If you wrap it in a Makefile it could look like:

```
.DEFAULT_GOAL := run

run:
    docker-compose up -d containerA
    sleep 10
    docker cp containerA:/seed-file seed-file
    docker-compose up -d containerB
```