# How to share files between sibling-containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

i want to share a file between two docker-containers which are siblings.

`Container1` is created using a `docker-compose`-file and creates a file in his local file-system. Then it starts another container `Container2` as a sibling. The created file in `Container1` should be passed to `Container2` for further processing.

I've tried using a volume, but without any success. The shared volume contains the files when I execute `ls` inside `Container1`, but if I execute the same command in `Container2`, the mounted volume is empty.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you tell me the main goal that you want to achieve? (The goal that u have chosen this solution for)

Comment: `Container1` takes some data as an input, creates a file and should start a `Container2` which does some tasks depending on the content of the file. `Container2` is used in a fire-and-forget kind of way.

Comment: Did you try using a _named volume_, such a shown in [this example](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-share-data-between-docker-containers)?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that as well. As I've said, when I do `ls` on the volume in `Container1`, the files are there. If I do `ls` in `Container2`, the volume is empty.

Comment: You may find it more manageable and scalable to use a job queue like RabbitMQ to do this type of processing.  Send the content to be processed as the body of a message (if it's small enough), and have the "container 2" be a long-running worker process that accepts messages from the queue and does some work.  There are a lot of complications around sharing files (permissions, working in a clustered environment, ...) and using a job queue to decouple things can be better.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use NetCat for Windows to send a binary file to a TCP connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040817/how-to-use-netcat-for-windows-to-send-a-binary-file-to-a-tcp-connection)

Answer (score -2):

Dear Mamen the best way of sharing data between containerized apps/services is not file-sharing.

There are some best practices that I can point below:

1. Share your file using HTTP-based api between containers. (In your case share your file privately with Nginx is through a bridge network between docker containers.
2. Share your data/blob using Queue Management services like Active|Rabbit|Zero MQ.
3. POST your file to the receiver container using HTTP api (through a bridge between docker containers

Anyway, you can share data through volumes created and located in Host. To be clarified you can see [this](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-share-data-between-docker-containers) sample.

Comment: This is way to complex for my use-case. I don't want to build an API or use queues just to share one file with a newly created container.

As I've already said, I've tried using volumes but the volume is empty when inspected by the second container.